# Two Matzos at the Seder

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, matzah, minhag

Many Hagados show an option of using only 2 Matzos at the Seder as Nusach HaGra. Does anyone still do only 2 Matzos?

Comment: Reb Moshe feinstein did and I was told so do his sons I have no way of confirming it so I wont write it as an answer

Comment: @SimchasTorah - Do we have an existing standard of not considering answers _mipi sh'mu'a_ answers?

Comment: How many degrees of separation can still be considered mipi hashemua? We can confirm Rav Moshe's hanhaga by looking in the Arzei Levanon Haggadah.

Comment: @WAF - Any kind of source is fine; we just want people to document what their source is. Of course, ST is well within his rights to exercise discretion in not posting an answer based on a less reliable type of source.

Comment: My Arzei Levanon Haggadah is still packed away but I will look up Rav Moshe's minhag bl"n as soon as I unpack it.

Answer (score 4):

Reb Moshe Feinstein used two Matzaos as per Minhag HaGra brought down in both of these Haggadas
  [Artscroll Vayaged Moshe Haggadah](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=32443)  and the [Reb Moshe Haggadah](http://www.feldheim.com/haggadah-shel-pesach-rav-moshe-feinstein-zt-l-hebrew-only.html)

Answer (score 3):

The Zilberman family of Yerushalayim does everything al pi HaGra.